# Не могу вывести в данные в строку и в столбик одновременно

Tags: java

Задание:

Данные нужно вывести сначала в строку через пробел, а потом в столбик. Не получается сделать это одновременно (одно после другого).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int N = 10;
    int mas[] = new int[N];
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
        mas[i] = rand.nextInt(20) + 2;
        if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");
        }
        for (int j=2;j<N;j++){
        System.out.println(mas[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: очевидно надо занести данные в массив, а потом сделать пару циклов для горизонтали и для вертикали отдельно. ну или как минимум после этого кода сделать цикл для вертикального отображения

Comment: Я уже пытался сделать с отдельным циклом для вертикали, но оно начинало выводить все в столбик, а о строке не было и намека.

Comment: ну-ка покажи как ты это делал? добавь в вопрос. такого быть не может

Comment: Добавил в вопрос две строки, как это вижу я.)

Comment: нет. надо его совсем отдельно, а не в цикле делать...

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, создать точно такой же цикл как первый, но в конце сделать вывод в столбик через println?

Comment: да, это я и имею в виду. только уже без добавления `rand.nextInt(20) + 2;` в массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое чтоли нужно?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int N = 10;
int mas[] = new int[N];
for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
    mas[i] = rand.nextInt(20) + 2;
    if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");
    }
}

System.out.println();

boolean isFirst = true;
for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
    if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) {
        if (isFirst) {
            isFirst = !isFirst;
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(mas[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

`isFirst` - чтоб не дублировать первую цифру.

Будет что-то типа такого:

```
2 4 16 2 14 8 10 
4 
16 
2 
14 
8 
10
```

Comment: Это даже перебор.) Вы сделали что-то вроде координатной плоскости. Мне нужно, чтобы вышло
(2 4 16 2 14 8 10) сначала в строку, потом отступ, а потом это же только в столбик

Comment: @BattleMonster ну да, это я предположил. что может быть надо так. Если не так, то манипуляции с `isFirst` можно удалить

Comment: Да, направление я уловил и что-то даже получилось. Большое спасибо!